# How to create dynamic content in Google maps?

Tags: excel, google-maps

I have a disease forecast map to help predict a particular plant disease and help Agricultural growers in the UK decide whether of not they need to apply a fungicide to control the disease. See the following: 
[Phoma Leaf Spot Map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WymFnwqfjKdKA8gNpWY4kK2GNbE&usp=sharing)
 I am a Biologist, not a computer scientist/programmer and need help.
The map is generated from an excel file of Lats/Longs and data on disease progress.  At the moment, every day I have to open the excel file, (so the date changes to today and an "IF" statement calcualates the new disease parameters).  I then have to log in to google maps, delete yesterdays layer, upload the updated xls, tell it to use the lats and longs for the position of the markers and to use Site for the marker titles, then categorise the markers by "disease status" (3 categories), and then manually change the colours of the markers to green, yellow and red.  Is there anyway I can code this to happen automatically?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can ask code problems on the site. You need to provide example of your faulty code and the error. But do not expect people to write programs for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Spreadsheets
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets
and pair them with a Google Geochart.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart